# How to pivot Spark DF cols into rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to pivot a Spark DF columns into rows like the example below.

```
scala> df.show()
+----+--------------------+
|year|               String|
+----+--------------------+
|ina|List(Apple, 136, Train ...)...|
|inb|List(Orange, 4.36, car ...)...|
|ina|List(Apple,34, plane ...)...|
+----+--------------------+
```

And create an output DF as:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
|year|key|String|
+----+-------------+-------------+
|ina|Apple       |136  |
|inb|Car         |4.36 |
|ina|Orange      |34   |
```

How can I get the desired output? using explode?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider your value column as a json:

```
val mappingSchema = MapType(StringType, FloatType)
   
originalDF.withColumn("map", from_json($"value", mappingSchema)).select($"year", explode($"map")).show()
```

gives:

```
+----+------+---------+
|year|   key|    value|
+----+------+---------+
|2020| Apple|1064.3667|
|2020|   Car|   1434.2|
|2020|Orange| 104.3667|
|2020| Plane|    145.2|
|2020| Apple|  1064.37|
|2020| Train|    134.2|
+----+------+---------+
```

Rename your columns if it is necessary

Comment: it "explodes" the intermediate MapType which is created from the json